# codeigniter htaccess help needed

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

[My Site:](http://core01.0fees.net/exam/)

Why is my .htaccess file not working. My framework is CodeIgniter

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase http://core01.0fees.net/exam/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin   

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: this is my site
http://core01.0fees.net/exam/

htaccess is not working

Comment: thats a code igniter error page that it is displaying so the .htaccess should be working fine. `Unable to load the requested file: home/home.php` the error message it is currently displaying.

Comment: http://core01.0fees.net/

Comment: when i remove the htaccess file welcome controller loads .......... but when i restore it look what happens
http://core01.0fees.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line:

RewriteBase http://core01.0fees.net/exam/

To this:

RewriteBase /exam/

RewriteBase option use relative path from web root.

Comment: tried that but didnt work i have now move the files to the htdocs file and deleted the exam folder

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

Try this i use it is working fine for me.
  asset is the name of my application folder you can change it to your own.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|images|css|js|lib|img|bootstrap|favicon|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /asset/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unable to load the requested file: home/home.php

Comment: check your default controller in config routs

Comment: did you check your default controller in config routs and did you set it properly

Comment: when i remove the htaccess file welcome controller loads .......... but when i restore it look what happens
http://core01.0fees.net/

Comment: open config routs and change your default controller to the name of your own controller

Answer (score 0):

if you're working on linux environment try to lowercase first letter of file (home/home.php)
linux environment is case sensitive Home.php and home.php are not same thing in linux. your problem is most probably this